# Is it possible to use the require statement with BASE_URL?

Tags: php, require, base-url

I added the below code in my connection.php

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com/');
```

Now, Is it possible to use `BASE_URL` with `require` like

```
 require('".BASE_URL."/connection.php');
```

Why I am doing this because I have a connection file in my root folder and I have some files in the below path

```
view/admin/company/employee/empid/details.php
```

and I have to add the connection file inside  `details.php`. I can do using something like this(../../../../) but I don't want to do this.

Is there any best way to handle this?

Comment: Requiring via the file system, and requiring via HTTP, are two completely different things. In the latter case, you would only get the _output_ produced by the `connection.php` script. and not the actual PHP code it contained.

Comment: @CBroe, Can you help me out with this issue? I am not aware of this

Comment: Your attempt as described makes no sense to begin with - you can not define that constant _in_ the `connection.php`, and then expect to be able to use it to require that same script somewhere else - the constant will not exist at that point, _obviously_, because the script that defined it, was not required yet. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` as mentioned in the already existing answer is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Global Functions for this.

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

Also, you can use PHP magic functions

```
__DIR__
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Just little bit confused here do I need to use define('BASE_URL', '$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]'); ? Or  I have to use like this    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/connection.php');

Comment: If you are working on localhost (xampp) then $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] will returns C:/xampp/htdocs .... So you can combine "view/admin/company/employee/empid/details.php" with it.

Comment: I added like this on my page require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/connection.php'), and I got an error Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in. It's not showing my folder name after htdocs

Comment: That’s because DOCUMENT_ROOT points to the location, that is set as the document root for your server setup. If the file you want to require is not directly on that level, but further down, then you have to insert that part of the path as well.

Comment: _“do I need to use define('BASE_URL', '$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]'); ? Or I have to use like this require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/connection.php');”_ - do not overwrite BASE_URL with that. This is not a URL, but a file system path - so define a different constant for that, if you want to use one - `BASE_PATH` or something.